# Why are all my HTML elements formatted as links

Tags: html

Recently I have run into a problem that I can't wrap my head around.
I have made a HTML page that has aside code in it because for my project. I have to have css and
for some reason every element (image and paragraphs) has a link attached. I only want to format one one image. Please help me to find out what I did wrong.

I tried adding sections and that didnt work. Even grouping but still, it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>tech history GPU</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href="AHHHHH.css">
</head>

 <body>
 
 <header>
 <h1>GPU HISTORY</h1>
 </header>


<section> 

<aside> 
<a href="e.html"</a>  <img src="ui.png" alt="ui.pussyobruv.jpg">
</aside>
</section>


<section>
<aside2>
<img src="gpu.png" alt="gpu.png">
</aside2>
</section>


<section>
<asid3>
<h1>the gpu is one of the most important componets of the computer</h1>
 </aside3>
</section>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For one, please post the TEXT of the code, not an image. For two, it looks like you're ending your `<section>` (with `</section>`) more times than you begin one. Unfortunately questions like this don't fit here since they're bugs due to simple syntax errors. Learn to use Inspect mode in a browser to view the DOM tree which should obviate these errors.

Comment: Add code here as text, not links to images.

Comment: Looking at the image of your code, your HTML Is definitely not valid - besides the `<section>` issue. Also, while `<aside2>` is **technically** a valid HTML5 element, it should probably be using `<aside>` and CSS to style if it needs to be different.

Comment: Edit your snippet to include your CSS as well. There is a CSS box in the Stack Snippet interface

Comment: This is the offending code: `<a href="e.html"</a>  <img src="ui.png" alt="ui.pussyobruv.jpg">` - you aren't closing the opening `<a>`. Here's what it should be: `<a href="e.html"><img src="ui.png" alt="ui.pussyobruv.jpg"></a>` Notice how the `<a>` is closed after the the `href`? Then put the closing `</a>` after the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Dear Dezmond, welcome to Stack Overflow. You have provided the needed code to your closed question which made it show up in the reopen list. I have done a few edits to your question text to improve the question and cast the final vote to reopen. Please review the edits. A question text that has good grammar and punctuation and which is focused helps the volunteers here to help you! Please review the guide  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Like @disinfor wrote in the comment, you need to enclose elements that should be a link with `<a href="..."> (content) </a>`

- You wrote the close tag before the image tag and moreover forgot an angular bracket. This is the corrected code:
- The tags `<aside2>` and `<aside3>` are not valid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>tech history GPU</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href="AHHHHH.css">
</head>

 <body>
 
 <header>
 <h1>GPU HISTORY</h1>
 </header>


<section> 

<aside> 
<a href="e.html"> <img src="ui.png" alt="ui.pussyobruv.jpg"> </a>
</aside>
</section>


<section>
<aside>
<img src="gpu.png" alt="gpu.png">
</aside>
</section>


<section>
<aside>
<h1>the gpu is one of the most important componets of the computer</h1>
 </aside>
</section>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```